# How to solve ConcurrentModificationException when using a pair of lists in a recursive function?

Tags: java, list, recursion, concurrency, concurrentmodification

So I am trying to balance a binary search tree by recursively setting the children of each node:

```
public void balanceTheTree(){
    root = balance(keys, names);
}

public Node balance(List<Integer> keyList, List<String> nameList){
    buildArrays(root);
    if(root == null){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        int newRootIndex = keyList.size()/2;
        Node focusNode = new Node(keyList.get(newRootIndex), nameList.get(newRootIndex));
        focusNode.leftChild = balance(keyList.subList(0, newRootIndex), nameList.subList(0, newRootIndex));
        focusNode.rightChild = balance(keyList.subList(newRootIndex+1, keyList.size()),nameList.subList(newRootIndex+1, nameList.size()));
        return focusNode;
    }

}
```

buildArrays() uses an in order traversal to store the trees values (names) and keys (keys) in their respective Lists. Names is a `List<String>` and keys is a `List<Integer>`.

Unfortunately balance is throwing an exception at any line that attempts to access the lists.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(Unknown Source)
at BinaryTree.balance(BinaryTree.java:43)
at BinaryTree.balance(BinaryTree.java:45)
at BinaryTree.balanceTheTree(BinaryTree.java:34)
at tester.main(tester.java:30)
```

Where line 43 is `int newRootIndex = keyList.size()/2;`

Thanks!

```
public void buildArrays(Node focusNode){
    if(focusNode != null){
        buildArrays(focusNode.leftChild);

        names.add(focusNode.name);
        keys.add(focusNode.Key);

        buildArrays(focusNode.rightChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the list implementation that you are using?

Comment: In the method call the Lists being passed in are ArrayList<Integer> and ArrayList<String> for keys and names respectively

Comment: can you put up the code for `buildArrays`?

Comment: I added the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `keyList.subList()`, to which you are adding new elements and that is a reason for `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Instead of sublist, pass a *copy* of the actual sublist, e.g. `new ArrayList<>(keylist.subList(0, 4))`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use list iterator.renove() if you are using list.remove function
Option 2: Try CopyOnWriteArrayList with cost of performance
Option 3: Convert the list into array and do the manipulation